# Why Google My Business API returns an `attribute` which is not deprecated and then does not accept to set this attribute for the locations?

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I am using the new `GOOGLE My Business Information API` in JAVA, [according to this link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/attributes/list). I read all possible attributes that GOOGLE has considered for various `Categories` and the related `Attributes`. The API is supposed to return a value named `DEPRECATED` if the attribute is going to be deprecated. However, I have an attribute named: `attributes/pay_debit_card` which has a `BOOL` type and is not deprecated. The returned attribute is like the photo:
[image].

The problem is that when I send the updatedAttributes to Google according [according to this link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations/updateAttributes), the API returns an error:

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

The code works well for other attributes. I provide some abstract lines of my code in java while the attribute type is BOOLEAN:
supposing theAttributeId is a string value equal to `pay_debit_card` and the variable `myBusinessBusinessInformation` is the initializer of type `com.google.api.services.mybusinessbusinessinformation.v1.MyBusinessBusinessInformation` and also takes care of credentials.

```
    String attributeMask="attributes/"+theAttributeId;
    String name ="locations/"+locationId+"/attributes";
    List<Object> values=null;
    values=Arrays.asList(true); // for example to set it true
    Attribute attribute = new Attribute().setValueType(valueType).setValues(values).setName(theAttributeId);
                                attributes.add(attribute);

try {
UpdateAttributes request = myBusinessBusinessInformation.locations()
                                    .updateAttributes(name, new Attributes().setAttributes(attributes))
                                    .setAttributeMask(attributeMask);
                            request.execute();
}catch (IOException e) {
 System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to set this attribute for the respective location via the GBP UI?

Comment: I checked now for my other clients it works well for the exact same attributeId

Comment: @vpriesner
 {
  "error": {
    "status": "NOT_FOUND", 
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.", 
    "code": 404
  }
}The same error in GBP UI. for some clients works and for the other no

Comment: If there's an error in the UI as well, I would just report it to the GBP API support.